# Add semitransparent box around the Chapter title wich is in front of a picture

Tags: graphics, tikz-styles, layout

Seeing as I’m only started using LaTeX five days ago, there is a problem I would like to request the community's help as I can't figure out a way to get the layout I'm looking for.

I managed to add a picture to start a chapter. But waant to add a semi-transparent white box with rounded edges and a orange border around the chapter title. Is there a way to do this without using Tikz?

Or if using Tikz, is there a way to add the picture aswell as the box in the same command. If I try using Tikz, the picture always gets pushed to the side and the box around the title somehow flips vertical.

The code I use to get the screenwidth picture is the folowing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} 


%format chapter to add picture
\titleformat{\chapter} 
  {\fontfamily{qag}\huge\bfseries\printcurrentpicture}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\makebox[0cm][r]{\thechapter.\hspace{15pt}}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{50pt}{0pt}{50pt}

\newcommand{\printcurrentpicture}{%
  \vspace*{-\dimexpr\topskip+1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\lineskip}%
  \moveleft\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\vbox{%
    \hbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterpicture}%
    }
    \vspace{-80pt}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\chapterpicture}[1]{%
  \def\thechapterpicture{#1}%
}
```

The box I want to add looks something like the picture below.
[image]

Kind regards
A novice LaTeX starter.

Comment: I do not know enough about that, if what you want is an Ebook kind of file. But if you are trying to create a printed (to paper) book, then you will need to reduce artwork to flat png images (no transparency). You can create them by any means, as long as the final file has only flat artwork. This is not a technical limitation, it is a commercial practice.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, ie fully compilable code with the minimum number of lines that demonstrates your problem. [Creating a LaTeX Minimal Example](http://tug.ctan.org/info/dickimaw/dickimaw-minexample.pdf)